# get highest number from column

Tags: php, mysqli

I need to get the highest number from "topicid" column, the snippet below seems to work fine but was wondering if there is a better solution, maybe without the while loop?

```
<?php
   $tquery = "SELECT MAX(topicid) FROM post";
   $tresult = mysqli_query($connect,$tquery);

   while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($tresult)){

   $topidcount = $row['MAX(topicid)'] +1;

?>
   <input type="hidden" name="topicid" value="<?php echo $topidcount;?>" />
   <?php
   }
   ?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take out the `while` loop when you know there's only one row returned:

```
<?php
   $tquery = "SELECT MAX(`topicid`) FROM `post`;";
   $tresult = mysqli_query($connect, $tquery);

   // get the query result without the while loop
   $row = mysqli_fetch_array($tresult);

   $topidcount = $row['MAX(topicid)'] +1;
?>
```

Comment: Thank you Anton, "can't accept answer for 10 mins" so +1 for now.

Answer (score 2):

Surely there is a way better solution. A proper one I'd say.
You should alter your `topicid` field, making it `auto_increment`-ed.

So, when inserting new topic, just assign `NULL` to it's value, and next free number will be assigned automatically.
With your current setup you will face race conditions and inconsistent data. So, you should not assign new numbers manually.

As for the "without loop" solution, smart developer always ready to develop a tool to ease frequent tasks.
A custom function like this can be very handy:

```
function sqlOne($sql) {
    global $connect;
    $res = mysqli_query($connect,$sql) or trigger_error(mysqli_error($connect)."[$sql]");
    $row = mysqli_fetch_row($res); 
    return $row[0];
}
```

It can be stored somewhere and then get you desired data in one line

```
$title = sqlOne("SELECT title FROM post WHERE topicid=".intval($topicid));
```

Comment: topicid assigns posts to the same page based on the number set, ie topic starter post and its replies so ai is not an option, another way I guess would be to add a new table with a single ai row and `set+1` each time a topic is created but for now Antons solution is fine.

Answer (score 1):

Why are you using loop?

Max will be only 1 row.

Try:

```
<?php
   $tquery = "SELECT MAX(topicid) as max FROM post";
   $tresult = mysqli_query($connect,$tquery);
   $row = mysqli_fetch_array($tresult));
   $topidcount = $row['max'] +1;
?>
   <input type="hidden" name="topicid" value="<?php echo $topidcount;?>" />
```

Comment: ..Hense me asking the question, I knew there was a better way just didn't know it ;)

Answer (score 0):

You also don't need to use the column name.  The result has only one row and only one column, so just grab the single element:

```
<?php 
  $tquery = 'SELECT MAX(topicid) FROM post';
  $row = mysql_fetch_array(mysqli_query($connect,$tquery));
  $topid = $row[0];
?>
```